# How to receive types built from functors as argument to functions in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, functor

I'm studying functors, and I was trying to receive a `Module.t` as argument where `Module` is the result of a functor call `SomeFunctor(sig type t = int end)` but I receive `Unbound type constructor FooInt.t`

Here is the code

```
module type Foo_S = sig
  type t
end

module type Foo = sig
  type t
  val id : t -> t
end

module FooExtend(Arg : Foo_S) : (Foo with type t := Arg.t) = struct
  let id a = a
end

module FooInt = FooExtend(Int)
module FooString = FooExtend(String)

let () =
  assert (FooInt.id 1 = 1);
  assert (FooString.id "x" = "x")

module FooSimple = struct type t = int end

let foo (x : FooInt.t) = (* This doens't compile: Unbound type constructor FooInt.t *)
  FooInt.id x

let foo' (x : FooSimple.t) = (* This works fine *)
  FooInt.id x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two changes are needed, 1) `type t` needs to be defined in the module, and 2) don't use destructive substitution:

```
module FooExtend(Arg : Foo_S) : (Foo with type t = Arg.t) = struct
  type t = Arg.t
  let id a = a
end
```

The problem is that destructive substitution (`type t := Arg.t`) replaces every occurrence of `t` with `Arg.t`. Instead you want to specify type equality, using a "sharing constraint" (`type t = Arg.t`).

Notice the difference in the resulting module signature between the two:

```
module FooExtend(Arg : Foo_S) : (Foo with type t := Arg.t) = struct
  type t = Arg.t
  let id a = a
end

module FooExtend : functor (Arg : Foo_S) -> sig 
  val id : Arg.t -> Arg.t
end
```

```
module FooExtend(Arg : Foo_S) : (Foo with type t = Arg.t) = struct
  type t = Arg.t
  let id a = a
end

module FooExtend : functor (Arg : Foo_S) -> sig
    type t = Arg.t
    val id : t -> t
end
```

Comment: Amazing! 

I didn't get the why I need `type t  = Arg. t` inside the `struct ... end` if I already said `with type t = Arg.t`, I feel that I'm missing something.

Comment: `with type t = Arg.t` just alters the module *type*. You need `type t = Arg.t` for the module definition to also match the type.

Comment: If you're still wondering why you have to do it twice, you could also have `type t = Arg.t` in the module definition, but omit `with type t = Arg.t` in the type. In that case `type t` would be "abstract", meaning its definition would be hidden from outsiders.